# Veda vyasa mahabaratham

Tags: puranas, ramayana, vyasa, valmiki, mahabharata

Where will I get mahabarat books written by maharishi veda vyasa in India? Also I wanted to get srimad Bhagavadam by vyasa and ramayan written by valmiki. When I search for such books I don't get the one that is written by vyasa and valmiki instead I get the ones with other authors.

Is my search correct or should I go for some  other authors can you please clear my confusion and where will I get these books to buy.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Hinduism SE! ..."instead I get the ones with other authors" --they are translators actually who translated Vyasa's/Valmiki's Sanskrit language work into English/Hindi languages..

Comment: [Gita Press Gorakhpur](https://gitapressbookshop.in/0728-महाभारत-हिन्दी-टीका-के-साथ-6-खंण्डों-में-mahabharat-with-hindi-commentary-in-6-volumes-) if you understand hindi please.